# Dependencies / Source of certain JAR files with Worklight version

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded an iFix from IBM fix central (6.1.0.02.20150520-1015) for Worklight Server and Worklight Studio but I could not locate the below jar files.

Applicationcenterdeploytool.jar
Ibm-java-x86_64-sdk-7.0.-6.0.bin
Json4j.jar
Wlpdevelopers-runtime-8.5.5.2.jar

Can you confirm if the above jar files are also specific to worklight version and will be seen post WL server installation or are they generic files which can used with any WL version which can be used by jenkins build scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ibm-java-x86_64-sdk-7.0.-6.0.bin - this is IBM's version of Java. This is not bundled with either a GM or iFix or Fix Pack. You're downloading this yourself prior to any installation, if you choose to use it.
- Wlpdevelopers-runtime-8.5.5.2.jar - I have no idea what that is. Looks like some WAS or WAS Liberty profile file, which you also install separately from Worklight
- Applicationcenterdeploytool.jar - located post-install at install-directory/ApplicationCenter/tools/applicationcenterdeploytool.jar and is the deploy tool of Application Center, used by the ant task scripts.
- Json4j.jar - located post-install at install-directory/ApplicationCenter/tools/json4j.jar and is used to handle the JSON file format